# Using php to populate html table

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, xml

I need to populate a table with data regarding 10 countries using a .php and .html file. I have downloaded XAMPP (7.1.8) I am working on a MacBook Pro 2012 running Sierra (can not get XAMPP-VM to run - get a signal killed error message on start up).

I have created the database testdb in MySql and coded the database.html file and the getuser.php file as below and saved them to the htdocs folder on the server - but when it renders, it isn't picking up the xml file or the data within.

I believe the problem is either on line 46 in the php or line 36 in the html, but I don't know enough about php to to know how to change it to make it work. Any help would be much appreciated,

Thanks

Suze

database.html

```
<head>

    <script>

        function showUser (str) {
            if (str=="") {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";

                return;
            }

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)  {

                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest ();

            } else { // code for IE6, IE5

                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject ("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function () {

                if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {

                    document.getElementById("hint").innerHTML=this.responseText;
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <form>

    <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">

        <option value ="">Select a country:</option>

        <option value ="1">United Kingdom</option>

        <option value="2">France</option>

        <option value="3">Germany</option>

        <option value="4">India</option>

        <option value="5">Hungary</option>

        <option value="6">Ireland</option>

        <option value="7">Greece</option>

        <option value="8">USA</option>

        <option value="9">Japan</option>

        <option value="10">Spain</option>

        </select>

    </form>

<br>

    <div id="hint"><b>Country info will be highlighted below</b></div>

</body>
```

getuser.php

```
<style>

    table {

        width: 100%;

        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table, td, th {

        border: 1px solid black;

        padding 5px;

    }

    th {text-align: left;}

</style>

</head>
```

```
<?php

$q = intval ($_GET['q']);


$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

if (!$con) {

    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"testdb");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


echo "<table

<tr>

<th>Country</th>

<th>Capital City</th>

<th>Currency</th>

</tr>";

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>" . $row['Country'] . "</td>";

    echo "<td>" . $row['Capital City'] . "</td>";

    echo "<td>" . $row['Currency'] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);

?>

</body>
```

Comment: Edited to check open and closing of tags. The opening head and body tags are in the original code for the .php... and they copied across here - but they aren't showing which is odd. But they are there

Comment: My suggestion is that you check every part of your script for itself. Check if your PHP script works and gathers the information you require. Check your AJAX request, if it returns simple text. If every part works for itself, you should combine them.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that you fetch an Array instead of an Assoziation.
Use mysqli_fetch_assoc(). Then you can access the Array like you do.

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))

and close the first table tag.

Comment: Susan Cooper is using `fetch_array()` which has the default return type  `MYSQLI_BOTH`. She can use both associative and numeric keys to get the values. Your answer is not correct.